How to create bridge (br0) in Vagrant using private network
I have brought up Vagrant machine with private_network. It creates eth1 interfaces. I want to create bridge using that IP.
After vm is up, if I create br0 with the same IP and remove the IP from eth1, I lose the IP connectivity as well as internet access in VM. The ssh  doesn't work but vagrant ssh  still works.
My vagrant and virtual box knowledge isn't great. So can someone help me with this? Is this usecase even valid? How can I create br0 instead of eth1 using private ip?
